# Can't read a word from a 187-year-old document

Tags: single-word-requests, writing

I have a land deed from the year 1824 for some land in the province of Upper Canada (back when that was a province).

Some photos of the deed can be seen [in this imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfggR.jpg).

I am attempting to read which day March 1824 the document was signed. The hand writing is simply indistinguishable from our modern form, so any help would be appreciated. Logically, it would make sense if it was a number of the month.

Here is the specific section towards the end of the document:

[image]

Here is the word with some editing to make the shape stand out.

[image]

My guess is: "Hveutitath", obviously not a word.

Comment: I believe that says `Twentieth`

Comment: Looks the same as current cursive.

Comment: I think you're right @Phoenix . I was just unable to read it. My other guesses were "seventeenth", another person I asked thought "eleventh". Please put your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: This has got to be "too localised".

Comment: 127 views in 4 hours.. I bet when they wrote that they never *imagined* how many random people would be reading it in the future :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe that says **Twentieth**.  With an oddly formed "**e**" in the "**eth**" and both **T**s crossed by a single stroke.